# Is there any way to get the data from sql lite table?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql

I am implementing an app related to SQLite. In that app I created one table

```
id   hour   date  month   year   values
1    10:00  2     march   2012   20
2    11:00  2     march   2012   30
```

I am entering values in the table in every hour. So, imagine it will keep on going: After two months I want to get all values info related to month equals march like day wise.

Like total values info of month march and date 2nd.

Comment: Did you try this site: www.Google.com. They have plenty of good tutorials over there. Its worth a look.

Comment: read this  http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/    I think this will help you

Comment: I think you should also enter your date as 'dd-MM-yyyy mm-ss' in table and set the datatype of that column to Date so that you can Query it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write queries to pull the info for you, then iterate through the returned cursor to add them up.

An example query:

```
public Cursor getValue(String month, String day) {
    return mDb.query(YOUR_TABLE, new String[] { RECORD_ROWID,
        RECORD_HOUR, RECORD_VALUE }, RECORD_MONTH + "=" + month + " AND " + RECORD_DATE + "=" day,
        null, null, null, null);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use ormlite in your application it will make your life easy.
visit the following links
http://ormlite.com/android/examples/

http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://logic-explained.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-ormlite-in-android-projects.html&usg=AFQjCNEfVT93jMBzwzDdkacN3wfJbdBenQ

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not answer the question...

Comment: You have to write queries according to your needs and you can fetch data from tables.I suggested ormlite since it will become easier to deal with.